# Не могу добавить наследника в мапу (Wildcards)

Tags: java, wildcards

Компилятор ругается на то что передаю наследника класса Animal в Мапу.
Cat его наследует, но в Мапу добавить не могу. Компилятор выдает:

> The method put(capture#1-of ? extends Animal, Integer) in the type
> Map<capture#1-of ? extends Animal,Integer> is not applicable for the
> arguments (Cat, int)

Не понимаю почему это происходит. Помогите.

```
Cat sebas = new Cat("Себастьян", 10);
    Animal cat = new Animal("Кошка", 1);
    Map<? extends Animal, Integer> animals = new HashMap<>();
    animals.put(sebas, sebas.getAnimalID());
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно заменить **extend** на **super**. Подробее с примерами про wildcard можно прочитать [тут.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/wildcards-in-java/)

```
 Map<? super Animal, Integer> animals = new HashMap<>();
        Animal cat = new Cat();
        Cat cat2 = new Cat();
        animals.put(cat, 1);
        animals.put(new Animal(), 2);
        animals.put(cat2, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Замените `Map<? extends Animal, Integer> animals = new HashMap<>()` на `Map<Animal, Integer> animals = new HashMap<>()`должно сработать.

Comment: Не улавливаю разницы. И объяснение причины и почему замена поможет не помешает.